# how to hide one statement and reveal another?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to show 1 section of my HTML page and hide the rest.
I also create a "next" button and a "previous" button to scroll through the bunch. But the website seemed to be unaffected by this.

```
 next1 = function () {

    if ($("#p1").css("display") !== "none") {
        $("#p2").show()
        $("#p1").hide()
        $("#p3").hide()
    } 

    else if ($("#p2").css("display") !== "none") {
        $("#p3").show()
        $("#p1").hide()
        $("#p2").hide()
    }

    else if ($("#p3").css("display") !== "none")) {
        alert("This is the end.")
     }

}

prior = function () {
    if ($("#p1").css("display") !== "none")) {
        alert("No pages before this.")
        }

    else if ($("#p2").css("display") !== "none")) {
        $("#p1").show()
        $("#p2").hide()
        $("#p3").hide()
    }

    else if ($("#p3").css("display") !== "none")) {
        $("#p2").show()
        $("#p1").hide()
        $("#p3").hide()
    } 

}

setup = function () {
    $("#p2").css("display") == "none")
    $("#p3").css("display") == "none")
    $("#next1").click(next)
    $("#prior").click(prior)

}
$(document).ready(setup)
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<script src="page.js"></script>
<title>A Story</title>
</head>
<body>


<section id="p1">
<p>...4</p>
</section>

<section id="p2">
<p>..2.</p>
</section>

<section id="p3">
<p>..1.</p>
</section>


<button value="prior">previous</button>    <button value="next">next</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I did anything wrong with the formatting or phrasing, please tell me. thank in advance

Comment: Hi @FalseLiu -- You should check out the [ask] page.  You've provided incomplete code here-- there is no corresponding HTML.  Also there appear to be quite a few errors in what is shown.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problems are in your if statements.

```
if ($("#p1").css('display') !== 'none') {
    $("#p2").show()
    $("#p1").hide()
    $("#p3").hide()
}
```

if($("#p1").show()) { ... cant work because show is a function and not a property of an object

normaly jquery uses display none to hide dom elements

by the way, you forgot to load jquery in the posted code.

next problem is. that your script is available before the browser has build up the dom. set the script tag behind the body tag.

please have a short look into the jquery docs and look what $(document).ready() does and why all people use it.

Comment: well, I tried to do it separately. one file for java, another for html.

Comment: so, i am sorry, but i thought the "$" loads the file.

Comment: @FalseLiu the $ is just a shortcut for JQuery, and this must be included if you use ist.